Definition of a non-constant function, need of $x_1 \neq x_2$
I have been wondering about the definition of a non-constant function $f: X \to Y$.
The definition of constant function are

(Definition 1)- A function $f:X \to Y$ is a constant function if for all $x_1$ and $x_2 \in X$, we have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Negation of this statement, that is the definition of a non-constant function would ideally be

(Definition 2)- A function $f:X \to Y$ is a non-constant function if there exists $x_1$ and $x_2 \in X$, such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$

Alternative Definitions

(Definition 3)- A function $f:X \to Y$ is a constant function if there exists $y \in Y$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have $f(x)=y$

Negation of this statement, that is the definition of a non-constant function would ideally be

(Definition 4)- A function $f:X \to Y$ is a non-constant function if for all $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$, such that $f(x) \neq y$

My Question is
1- I have used the standard method to negate a mathematical statement. However I have seen in many texts, that we need $x_1 \neq x_2$. I do not understand the need to write $x_1 \neq x_2$ in the definition of a non-constant function. Even ChatGPT mentions that we cannot exclude $x_1 \neq x_2$, however it cannot provide reasonable justifications.

Your four definitions are correct. We don't need to write $x_1\ne x_2$ in definition 2 because it is implied by $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$.

As expected chatGPT came back with nonsense again. Please remove any reference to this dumb bot.

Wait zero2infinity. Definition 3 is not equivalent to definition 1, because of the exceptional "empty map" from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$. I am tempted to privilegiate definition 1.

Definitions 1 and 2 are equivalent if $X$ is nonempty and are different otherwise.

I feel compelled to explicitly second the admonition to be extremely skeptical of mathematical “pronouncements” from ChatGPT. ChatGPT is roughly like a 12-year-old doing a school assignment by hurriedly copy/pasting they found on the internet without really understanding it. I’ve often seen it produce hilariously wrong statements about very basic mathematical concepts.

Don't hate me for using ChatGPT. Whatever ChatGPT says, I always take it with a pinch of salt. Its is sometimes just quicker, and sometimes helpful

People aren't hating you for using ChatGPT. They are warning you that it is often unhelpful for stuff like this. But they might hate people who make posts like "ChatGPT said something and I didn't understand it", since those could flood the site very quickly if left unchecked, since ChatGPT is wrong so often.
